# SKSpriteNode does not change its position

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I am trying to change the position of a SKSpriteNode after the user has ended touching the screen. The x and y positions should be random, but of course still on the screen.

Here is the function I wrote:

```
//Move object to a random position on the screen
func randomPosition(object: SKSpriteNode){
    object.position.x = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(UIScreen.main.bounds.width)))
    object.position.y = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(UIScreen.main.bounds.height)))
}
```

But unfortunately the node does not move reliably. Most of the time it just rotates a little bit. (it looks very much like a bug)

Here is the place where I call the function from above:

```
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    ...
    randomPosition(object: enemy)
    ...
}
```

When I call the randPosition-Function only once, for example in the didMove Function, then it does work perfectly

**Thank you in advance!**

Comment: my guess is `enemy` is a new instance and is not the one that you are seeing on the scene.  So logically, `enemy` did change position, just not the desired one.  FYI, you should show all code that still allows you to reproduce your problem.  As of right now if you made a new project using just the code you had, you would not reproduce your results (It would actually error out on you)

Comment: Are you setting the camera to screen coordinates? because if not SK doesn't use UIKit's coordinate system so trying to specify location in screen space is not going to work.  In any case you still would have to inset the screen by 1/2 the object width and 1/2 the object height to make sure it doesn't spill out of the screen.